# Can phase transitions be predicted from the fundamental laws of physics?

Tags: phase-transition

Physicst Robert Laughlin says in his book that quantum mechanics can not be used to derive the mathematical laws that govern phase transitions. Is this true?

Comment: Note that "Yes/No" answers make poor fits for this site because the answer isn't long enough to be a valid answer. Could you rephrase the question to be more open-ended and allow for a longer response?

Comment: I am not familiar with the text book, but are you asking about first-order or second order phase transitions?